# How to calculate running total per customer for previous 365 days in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, window-functions

I am trying to calculate a running total per customer for the previous 365 days using pandas but my code isn't working.  My intended output would be something like this:

| date | customer | daily_total_per_customer | rolling_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-07-29 | 1 | 100 | 100 |
| 2016-08-01 | 1 | 50 | 150 |
| 2017-01-12 | 1 | 80 | 230 |
| 2017-10-23 | 1 | 180 | 260 |
| 2018-03-03 | 1 | 0 | 180 |
| 2018-03-06 | 1 | 40 | 220 |
| 2019-03-16 | 1 | 500 | 500 |
| 2017-04-07 | 2 | 50 | 50 |
| 2017-04-09 | 2 | 230 | 280 |
| 2018-02-11 | 2 | 80 | 360 |
| 2018-05-12 | 2 | 0 | 80 |
| 2019-05-10 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

I tried the following:

```
df_3 = df_3.set_index(['customer', 'date']).sort_values(by='date')

rolling_sum = df_3.rolling('365d', on='date')["daily_total_per_customer"].sum()
df_3["rolling_total"] = rolling_sum
```

And I get the following error

> ValueError: invalid on specified as date, must be a column (of DataFrame), an Index or None
> To recreate the code:

```
dates = ['2016-07-29',
'2016-08-01',
'2017-01-12',
'2017-10-23',
'2018-03-03',
'2018-03-06',
'2019-03-16',
'2017-04-07',
'2017-04-09',
'2018-02-11',
'2018-05-12',
'2019-05-10',
]


customer = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]

daily_total = [100,50,80,180,0,40,500,50,230,80,0,0]


df = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates,
            'customer': customer,
            'daily_total_per_customer':daily_total,})
```

Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Annotated code

```
# Parse the strings to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Sort the dates in ASC order if not already sorted
df = df.sort_values(['customer', 'date']) 

# Group the dataframe by customer then for each group
# calculate rolling sum on 'daily_total_per_customer'
s = df.groupby('customer').rolling('365d', on='date')['daily_total_per_customer'].sum()

# Merge the result with original df
df.merge(s.reset_index(name='rolling_total'))
```

---

```
         date  customer  daily_total_per_customer  rolling_total
0  2016-07-29         1                       100            100
1  2016-08-01         1                        50            150
2  2017-01-12         1                        80            230
3  2017-10-23         1                       180            260
4  2018-03-03         1                         0            180
5  2018-03-06         1                        40            220
6  2019-03-16         1                       500            500
7  2017-04-07         2                        50             50
8  2017-04-09         2                       230            280
9  2018-02-11         2                        80            360
10 2018-05-12         2                         0             80
11 2019-05-10         2                         0              0
```